# Rename files based on specific text in file, file contains lots of Spaces and other text

Tags: powershell, batch-rename

I have been trying to get this to work without success.   I have searched here and elsewhere for help and tried everything I could think of, the issue is its selecting additional text, I then get errors in the powershell script because the Filename contains odd characters that are system characters.

I have multiple files, they are plain text files.  Here is the specific line of text I need to select and rename from

```
"RECORDER ID: TEST1234               GROUP:  TEST     START TIME: 08/09/22 02:01"
```

There are multiple spaces after `TEST1234` (like ten or more spaces)
This is the 3rd line of txt in the file. 2nd line of text is blank.

The filename is currently a string of numbers ".EU"
I want to rename the file to be "`TEST1234.EU`" based on this above example.  here is the script I tried

```
cd C:\temp
$files = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
select-string -Path "*.*" -Pattern "RECORDER ID:" | ForEach-Object {   
    $old_filename = $_.Filename
    $new_filename = $_.line -replace "^.*RECORDER ID = ""","" -replace """.*$",""  
    $null = $files.Add(@{"old"=$old_filename;"new"=$new_filename})
}
$files |ForEach-Object{
    $old_filename = $_.old
    $new_filename = $_.new
    rename-item $old_filename $new_filename -Force
}
```

`$new_filename` ends up containing the whole pattern string, I need to split it after the first space after the `TEST124`, but I cannot figure out how to split it so its a valid filename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the line for the new name variable with the following:

```ps
$new_filename = $_.line -replace "RECORDER ID: (\w+).+", '$1.txt'
```

`TEST1234` is captured and reused to replace the line content, and thus becomes  `$new_filename`'s value.

Your code will be:

```ps
$files = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
select-string -Path "*.*" -Pattern "RECORDER ID:" | ForEach-Object {   
    $old_filename = $_.Filename
    $new_filename = $_.line -replace "RECORDER ID: (\w+).+", '$1,txt'  
     $files.Add(@{"old"=$old_filename;"new"=$new_filename})
}
$files |ForEach-Object{
    $old_filename = $_.old
    $new_filename = $_.new
    rename-item $old_filename $new_filename -Force
}
```

Comment: Awesome, you are amazing!.  Thanks so much, but it removes the File extension.   How do I get it to leave the file extension.   Its not a big deal, as I can just make another script to add it back, but would be great if it could leave it (or change it to .TXT which is what another script I have does)

Comment: @Icebreaker808 See edit. I have replaced `$1` with `$1.txt` to add `.txt` extension.

Comment: That did it.  Appreciate it!